# iOS: Programmatically-added UILabel not appearing above storyboard views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I'm following a tutorial wherein the tutor has added a `UIScrollView` and a nested `UIView` to the primary View via the storyboard. It's at a point where he's dragged a `UILabel` onto the storyboard, but I would much rather be adding these elements programmatically, so I attempted to do just that. Within my `viewDidLoad()` function I've added this basic code:

```
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 100, 200, 50));
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    label.text = "Hello!";

    self.view.insertSubview(label, aboveSubview: self.scrollView);
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(label);
```

This works and runs without error... except that the UILabel is behind everything else. If I click **View Debug Heirarchy** I can see my bright red label has been added, but behind everything else - despite trying to initially insert it *above* the scrollview, and additionally trying `bringSubviewToFront`.

Is there something else I'm missing? Or is this an issue with trying to mix and match between adding stuff programmatically versus via the storyboard?

Comment: What do you have setup in the storyboard? Is the scroll view added there? Given that setup, your code works fine for me. The label is in the front (even without the bringSubviewToFront line). Also there's no need to use insetSubview; if you use addSubview, the view you add last will be the top most view.

Comment: Yep: in the storyboard it goes (in order of ascendency) `View -> ImageView | [adjacent] Scroll View -> UIView`. If I programmatically add a `UILabel` in `ViewDidLoad()` in the ViewController, it appears as the first item within the root view, behind everything else. I would *assume* that it works the way you said, but it doesn't appear to (at least in this instance), which is frustrating. Similarly, if I add to the scrollView or contentView, it appears as the first item in those views, behind everything else.

Comment: Hmm....  I can't explain that. That's not what happens when I do it.